# How to load faster WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, window

After years of working on C# windows forms, I decided to check WPF technology.
In our company we have mostly dual core 2 GB RAM computers running on windows XP with 384 MB    graphic card on board.

Windows forms are loading very fast, but when I tried to load empty WPF window using
Visual Studio 2008 SP1, it took about 1.5 sec to load the form. 
I loaded the WPF window from existing win forms application.
I assume in VS 2010 it will be even slower. VS 2012 won't even run on XP.

Is there is a way to speed it up ? Or this technology requires better hardware ?

PS. When I close the window, and reopen WPF it loads very fast.

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2007/10/10/improving-wpf-applications-startup-time.aspx) might be of interest.

Comment: Your hardware is quite anemic, WPF requires loading a great deal of DLLs.  Not that much you can do about that, RAM and disk are the constraints.  Otherwise a good reason to ask for new machines, it is about time.

Comment: possibly unrelated, but hardware is cheaper than development time, and medical insurance for the developers who get testicular cancer because of winforms. Buy better machines and forget winforms forever. BTW, make sure you use .Net 4.5 or at least 4.0, because WPF 3.5 is full of bugs and unusable.

Comment: WinForms causing testicular cancer? Now that's a new one, @HighCore. Got a link to that study?

Answer (score 0):

Loading empty WPF window from another WPF window reduced the time to 15 milliseconds.
Loading from Winform took actually more than 2 seconds.

So the time improvement was drastic.

Comment: The issue is that it takes a while to initialize the framework on a cold boot. That cost is only paid the first time you launch an app that uses the framework. Subsequently, they should launch rather quickly. If not, like others have said, you need to update your hardware; WPF is quite resource intensive.

Answer (score -2):

The speed really shouldn't matter. It really isn't that slow. I have WPF application and it takes 2 seconds on top of loading some data from database. Run the App without debugging in Release mode. Also don't load the WPF from Win Forms.